# Filter Snapshot Version

Tags: linux, bash, maven, jenkins, nexus

I am working on maven project using jenkins, gitlab and nexus. Can I write a script to take the snapshot version without using maven help plugin.

```
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

I need output like this.

```
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Comment: Its not clear what you are really looking for and where are you stuck. Can you please elaborate what exactly you are trying to do? I don't think there is a problem with using SNAPSHOT versions as long as its a dev environment.

Comment: Actual requirement is to write a shell command to take the output of pom version attribute. It should display linux shell as `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`

Comment: I used grep command. `cat pom.xml | grep "SNAPSHOT"`. and output is `<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>`. Now I want to remove `<version>` from this output.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is way to do it without any further tools:

```
grep -ri "<version>" /tmp/config.pom |head -n 1 |sed -e 's/^[ \t]*<version>\([^<]*\)<.*$/\1/'
```

You just need to adapt the **/tmp/config.pom** path.

Comment: `without any further tools`, but this is fragile. apart from the working on Xml with regex problem, why `cat file`? why `grep | sed`? and what if a pom had (usually it does) multiple `<version>` elements?

Comment: **cat**, and then **grep** was only for legibility, but it can be reduced to a **grep -r**.  True if there are multiple <version> tag; it is fragile. In this version, we can add a head instruction, supposing it will be the project's Version will be the first occurrence, but it is not 100% guarantee.  I updated my answer consequently.

Comment: `cat pom.xml |grep -i "<version>" |sed -e 's/^[ \t]*<version>\([^<]*\)<.*$/\1/' | awk '{print $1; exit}'` I used `awk` command and I got the output which I expected. `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`

Comment: You don't need awk, after the sed instruction.

Answer (score 1):

If your maven POM file looks like this

```
cat config.pom
<project>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

You should use XML aware parsing tool like `xmlstarlet` (instead of text oriented tool like `sed`, `awk`) to extract the version string:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "project/version" -n config.pom
```

`-t` : template
`-v` : extract value of xpath `project/version`
`-n` : add a new line

Comment: right track. but pom.xml usually has a default namespace. It would be good to think about it.

Comment: @Kent Correct, and option `-N` will help. Given OP's example, I couldn't set it...